# Method lookup of "missing_method" in ruby

Tags: ruby

I am quite familiar with method lookup in ruby if method is present. What I am confused by is the following:

Ruby calls `method_missing` method if it doesn't find a method of that name in the hierarchy up to the highest level.
If I override the `method_missing` method down the hierarchy tree, then call a method which is not in the tree and after going all the up and not finding such a method, how does it come down the tree to execute the overridden `method_missing` in lower order class or module?

Does the method lookup for `method_missing` once again start from the same place where the method lookup for the so called method (which was not found) was started?

Simple code is below. I know ruby users are quite familiar with it:

```
module M
    def report
        puts "module M method report()"
    end
    def method_missing(ob)
        puts ob.class
        puts "No such method found"
    end
end

class C 
    include M
end

class D < C
end

obj = D.new
obj.report
obj.unkown_method
```

The expected output is:

```
module M method report()
Symbol
No such method found
```

The second line of output was just to check what type of argument this `method_missing` method takes.

Answer (score 1):

> Does the method lookup for method_missing once again start from the same place where the method lookup for the so called method (which was not found) was started ??

Yes.

Comment: Concise, aren't you? :)

Comment: What more can I say? :)